# Solar systems hogging the amps

Tags: amperage, solar-energy

In designing a solar-powered system, one thing I notice is that it is amp heavy for everything except lights.

With lights you can get 1600 lumen LED lights that are 8 watts, just 0.75 amp. Compared to a normal 100W incandescent bulb which is about 1 amp, I am doing good. (by "good" I mean not needing fat wires)

For a desktop computer, however, which draws about 200 Watts (or more), the amperage at 12V is 16 Amps and you are already near the maximum for a standard household 20-amp circuit. Plug in anything else, like a vacuum cleaner, monitor, printer or something else, and fuses are going to start to blow. The same computer on a 110V household AC circuit maxing out at 450W would only be about 4-5 amps.

So, what is the solution to this problem? Wire the house with 60 AMP circuits?

I notice that 6 AWG wire and connectors seem to be popular with solar energy outfitters, so maybe that is exactly what you have to do: fit big fat wires?

Comment: This is the reason (well, one of) the house is wired for 110/220V rather than 12V...

Comment: Use an Inverter!

Comment: "For a desktop computer, however, which draws about 200 Watts (or more), the amperage at 12V is 16 Amps and you are already near the maximum for a standard household 20-amp circuit."  I don't think that statement is correct.  Household wiring is rated at 20A at the rated V (not 12V).  At 20A@120V = 2400W.  I think you should be able to safely draw an equivalent amount of power at 12V, so you could probably draw 200A@12V without creating excessive heat in your power wires.  I'm not an EE or PE, so perhaps an EE in here can clarify that for you.

Comment: @DIYser: You CANNOT draw 200 amps (at any voltage) through the #12 wires used for a 120 volt 20 amp circuit.  The current a wire can carry is limited by the wire size, regardless of voltage.  The allowable wire size and current will also be affected by the allowable voltage drop.   If the voltage drop for a given current/wire size/wire length is 5 volts, that is insignificant on a 120 VAC circuit, but unacceptable at 12 volts.

Comment: You are mixing voltages and currents indiscriminately - a 100 watt 120 volt lamp will draw about 0.83 amps, but a 100 watt 12 volt lamp will draw 8.3 amps.  I expect that your LED lights are 12 volt DC, so they can't be compared directly with a 120 VAC lamp.

Comment: @PeterBennett I know what both device types draw. Yes, I was talking about 12v 8 watt lamps... and yes I can compare them and I did compare them as needing similar wire sizes, which is the point of the question.

Comment: @PeterBennett - How much current can the OP safely draw through a 20A rated conductor if he uses 12V -- 240W?? (i.e. 12V*20A)--that won't even warm a #12 wire.

Answer (score 3):

It's worse than it seems. If you drop (let's say) 2v down the supply wires, that's negligible compared to 120/240, but it's a big slice of 12v. So your wire gauge has to go up as the **square** of the current to maintain the delivered fraction of voltage at the far end.

The solution is to use as high a voltage for distribution as you can.

You *could* invert up your batteries before distribution, but that would be inefficient.

You could use 120v or 240v batteries, but that would be hazardous, and few standard items could use that DC voltage.

Telephone switch rooms, which tended to be battery powered, standardised on 48v distribution. This is just low enough to be considered touch safe by most electrical safety authories, and more efficent than 12v by a factor of 16 in wire cross section. As a result of that standardisation, there are many ICs and modules available that accept 48v input to give other outputs for local use.

A thing to consider is *where* in your house the batteries go. Can we assume charging will be slow and steady, and more tolerant of inefficiency than use, which might be short, peaky, and less tolerant of voltage drops? If so, put the batteries at the geographic centre of the house, to minimise the length of distribution wires, and run long wires from the panels for charging. This means not only will distribution voltage drops be lower, but shorter cables means you can afford a yet heavier gauge.

Comment: The problem there is that most solar panels and batteries are 12V, so it would have to be boosted to 48v and then brought down again. At the end of the day, big wires are going to be going to the computer.

Comment: You rarely try to get serious power from one single panel. So get 4 and series them.